# How to provide `Context` to async functions

Tags: asynchronous, rust

I am trying call the [poll_flush](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/io/trait.AsyncWrite.html#tymethod.poll_flush) method, which requires a [Context](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/core/task/struct.Context.html) object. I wonder how to obtain such object in tokio runtime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't call `poll_*` methods yourself unless you're writing a runtime, let the runtime do it for you using `await` on the corresponding `async` functions. Instead of calling `poll_flush` you should be calling [`AsyncWriteExt::flush().await`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/io/trait.AsyncWriteExt.html#method.flush).